# How to make xml in python does not automatically delete the whitespace in front and behind the string

Tags: python, xml

How can I make xml in python does not automatically delete the whitespace in front and behind the string, because the string (string nick) that must be executed is using whitespace in front and behind, I need to storm-bot jabber from (https://code.google.com/p/storm-bot/downloads/list)

For Example:

```
groupchat = 'jabberow@conference.jabber.ru'  
nick = '      sherlock     ' (example nick that using whitespace at front & behind)  

def order_visitor(groupchat, nick, reason):  
   iq = xmpp.Iq('set')  
   iq.setTo(groupchat)  
   iq.setID('ulti_visitor')  
   query = xmpp.Node('query')  
   query.setNamespace('http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin')  
   query.addChild('item', {'nick':nick, 'role':'visitor'})  
   iq.addChild(node=query)  
   JCON.send(iq)
```

Even I have tried with this way:

```
room = 'jabberow@conference.jabber.ru'  
nick = '      sherlock       ' (example nick that using whitespace at front & behind)  

setvisitor = xmpp.simplexml.XML2Node(unicode("<iq to='"+str(room)+"' type='set' id='itemmuc'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'><item role='visitor' nick='"+str(nick)+"'/></query></iq>").encode('utf8'))  

JCON.send(setvisitor)
```

But the result is a space that was in front and behind the string (string nick) is still deleted automatically and alwasy executed as "sherlock" and not "      sherlock     " even i already try to remove all strip() !!!

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: What python module are you using?  What does the generated XML actually look like?

Comment: i think i am using module simplexml.py from storm-bot and i am using python 2.7

Comment: that is xml for jabber conference to set user devoice or make visitor (stripping chatting rights)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this because even if you put spaces there they are not preserved when the XML file is parsed. The XML standard says whitespace in attribute values will be ”normalized”, i.e. stripped at front and end and any amount of whitespace within the stripped string is replaced by one space.

See the relevant section in the standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#AVNormalize

Comment: soo no solution for my problem ?